# Getting attribute names and doing some manipulations in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have to get the attribute names and do some manipulations based on the its name in XSLT.

Source:

```
<group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="XXX" xlink:title="sectionHeader_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
<group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="YYY" xlink:title="BodyParagraph_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
<group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="ZZZ" xlink:title="sectionHeader_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
<group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="AAA" xlink:title="sectionHeader_3" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
<group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="BBB" xlink:title="BodyParagraph_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
<group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="BBB" xlink:title="ConditionalText_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
```

I have to get the attribute `xlink:title` attribute in it and check for the following:

- when the attribute xlink:title contains string sectionHeader , I need to do some manipulations.
- when the attribute xlink:title  contains string BodyParagraph, I need to some manipulations.
- when the attribute xlink:title contains string ConditionalText, I need to some manipulations.

Can any one explain how it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the spirit of XSLT to use templates and pattern matching so that explicit conditional instructions are minimized or eliminated altogether.

**Here is how this can be done**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="group">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@xlink:title"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@xlink:title[contains(., 'sectionHeader')]">
   Found @xlink:title containing "sectionHeader"
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@xlink:title[contains(., 'BodyParagraph')]">
   Found @xlink:title containing "BodyParagraph"
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="@xlink:title[contains(., 'ConditionalText')]">
   Found @xlink:title containing "ConditionalText"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML fragment** (converted to a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="XXX" xlink:title="sectionHeader_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="YYY" xlink:title="BodyParagraph_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="ZZZ" xlink:title="sectionHeader_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="AAA" xlink:title="sectionHeader_3" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="BBB" xlink:title="BodyParagraph_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group  xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="BBB" xlink:title="ConditionalText_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
</t>
```

**the wanted result (something done in each case) is produced**:

```
   Found @xlink:title containing "sectionHeader"

   Found @xlink:title containing "BodyParagraph"

   Found @xlink:title containing "sectionHeader"

   Found @xlink:title containing "sectionHeader"

   Found @xlink:title containing "BodyParagraph"

   Found @xlink:title containing "ConditionalText"
```

**Do note**: You may consider using the `starts-with()` function rather than `contains()` .

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't modify parts of an existing XML file with XSLT, you have to copy everything and change those parts that should be different. Thus, I suggest to write a template that copies each node by default. Then you can add specialized templates for the group elements that meet your conditions, e.g. something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="group[contains(@xlink:title,'sectionHeader')]">
    <group>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>      
      <!-- modifications here -->
    </group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="group[contains(@xlink:title,'BodyParagraph')]">
    <group>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <!-- modifications here -->
    </group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="group[contains(@xlink:title,'ConditionalText')]">
    <group>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <!-- modifications here -->
    </group>
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you want to change the attribute values too, just replace the xsl:copy-of statements with the desired modifications.

Answer (score 1):

**Your source XML (some modifications done):**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <group id="x1" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="XXX" xlink:title="sectionHeader_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group id="x2" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="YYY" xlink:title="BodyParagraph_1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group id="x3" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="ZZZ" xlink:title="sectionHeader_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group id="x4" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="AAA" xlink:title="sectionHeader_3" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group id="x5" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="BBB" xlink:title="BodyParagraph_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group id="x6" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="BBB" xlink:title="ConditionalText_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
    <group id="x7" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="BBB" xlink:title="some_other_2" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"></group>
</root>
```

**XSL Document:**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <elements>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </elements>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//group[(contains(@xlink:title,'sectionHeader') or contains(@xlink:title,'BodyParagraph') or contains(@xlink:title,'ConditionalText'))]">
    <xsl:element name="element">
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="type"><xsl:value-of select="@xlink:type"/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**And the result:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<elements xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <element id="x1" type="simple" href="XXX"/>
    <element id="x2" type="simple" href="YYY"/>
    <element id="x3" type="simple" href="ZZZ"/>
    <element id="x4" type="simple" href="AAA"/>
    <element id="x5" type="simple" href="BBB"/>
    <element id="x6" type="simple" href="BBB"/>    
</elements>
```